Issue with COM Class Not Found in PHP 8.1 on XAMPP (Windows)
I'm encountering an error while trying to use the COM class in PHP 8.1 on XAMPP (Windows). The error message states: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'COM' not found".
I've checked my php.ini files in the XAMPP installation directory, but I couldn't find any reference to the COM extension. Instead, I see php.ini-development and php.ini-production files.

How can I enable the COM extension in PHP 8.1 on XAMPP (Windows)?
Should I make changes to php.ini-development or php.ini-production to enable the COM extension?
What steps should I follow to ensure that the COM extension is properly configured and loaded in my PHP environment?
Any assistance or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

COM Extension installation

COM Extension configuration

Installing a PHP extension on Windows

php.ini-development and php.ini-production are sample files included with the PHP installation. The actual configuration file in use is presumably somewhere else - I'm sure if you search for "XAMPP php.ini" or something you'll find plenty of information.
